# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)

Tags: android, objeto, null

*Hola soy nuevo en esto del desarrollo y estoy practicando con una app tipoUbr tengo el siguiente error si me pueden ayudar estaría muy agradecido

[image: Error:]

[DetailRequestActivity](https://pastebin.com/yK6T6Gj9)

[MyToollbar](https://pastebin.com/jRifjge5)

[MapClientActivity](https://pastebin.com/fBsv9CW7)

Error importante: `

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE && gpsActived())  {
            mFusedLocation.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        else if (requestCode == SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE && !gpsActived()){
            showAlertDialogNOGPS();
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Agrega donde trata de llamar setTitle(

Answer (score 0):

En la función donde llamas el toolbar debes verificar si el valor es diferente de `null` antes de asignarle el titulo a tu toolbar y además verifica si has añadido correctamente el widget toolbar en el archivo xml de la actividad donde lo usarás.

```
public static void show(AppCompatActivity activity, String title, boolean upButton) {
        Toolbar toolbar = activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(activity.getSupportActionBar() != null){
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton);
        }
    }
```